# Why function shows none for more output when using insert() method in lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using function to insert method to add a value in list as given below:
1. insert_value.py file as given below:

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):

  str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
  str_list4 = ['i', 't']

  if my_list == str_list3:

        front = my_list[:insert_position]
        back = my_list[insert_position:]
        return front + [value] + back

  elif my_list == str_list4:

        front = my_list[:insert_position]

        back = my_list[insert_position:]

        a= front +[value]+ back

        return a
```

2. insert_value_test_file.py as given below:

   ```
   import insert_value
   print("\ninsert_value Test")
   str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']

   new_list = insert_value.insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)

   print(new_list)

   str_list4 = ['i', 't']

   str_list4 = insert_value.insert_value(str_list4, 'p', 0)

   print(str_list4)

   str_list4 = insert_value.insert_value(str_list4, 's', -1)

   print(str_list4)

   str_list4 = insert_value.insert_value(str_list4, 's', 7)

   print(str_list4)
   ```

when running this file my output comes as :

> insert_value Test ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'] ['p',
>   'i', 't'] None None

Why None ???? for other inputs in str_list4.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the conditionals in insert_value evaluate to True after the first two calls, so insert_value has no return (returns None) for the last two calls.